# Creating .so file using ctypes when opencv is included in C++ code

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-extensions, .so

I am trying to create .so file of a c++ file(twocams.cpp) which includes main() and another C++ file (say abc.h). abc.c includes opencv. while creating an object using ctypes,

```
 g++ -fPIC -shared twocams.cpp -o twocams.so
 Test = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/administrator/Desktop/project/twocams/twocams.so')
```

i am getting error as:- 
undefined symbol: _ZN2cv12VideoCapturersERNS_3MatE

How to solve this problem? I want to use the c++ code in python. Any alternative is acceptable.

Comment: You have to link opencv

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a shared object and want to use it, you have to link your artifact against all dependencies of this shared object. E.g. I create a `libtwocams.so` of

```
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

void test() {
    cv::VideoCapture v;
    cv::Mat m;
    v >> m;
}
```

To use this shared object I have to link against libopencv_core, libopencv_videoio, libopencv_imgproc, libopencv_imgcodecs, libz and some more. I compile my program with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -ltwocams -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lz -lwebp -lpthread -ltiff -lpng
```

Another solution is to link the shared object against the dependent libraries. E.g.

```
g++ -fPIC -shared twocams.cpp -o -ltwocams -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_videoio -lz -lwebp -lpthread -ltiff -lpng
```

creates a shared library that makes the loader load all dependencies. You can check the dependencies with `ldd`.

The order of the libraries is important. If libA has a dependency to libB then you have to link against libA and then libB.

If you use opencv's shared library then you don't need to link all other dependencies.

Here is a step by step manual:

Install [conan](https://conan.io/)

Install [cmake](https://cmake.org/)

Add repository bincrafters to conan

```
conan remote add bincrafters https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan
```

Create:

- conanfile.txt
- CMakeLists.txt
- src/twocams.cpp
- build/

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
opencv/3.4.2@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake

[options]
opencv:shared=True
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(twocams)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_library(twocams SHARED src/twocams.cpp src/twocams.h)
target_link_libraries(twocams ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Go to `build` and install dependencies:

```
cd build
conan install .. --build missing
```

Build project with cmake:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Comment: Thanks @thomas, but the problem is i know how to use .so file and create shared object from it(to use it with other language like pyhton) but i do not know how to use shared library. It will be better if you can tell me how to create a .so file.

Comment: I also get an error ' cannot find -lwebp' while running the commands you suggested. Can you tell what needs to be done?

Comment: If your linker can't find libwebp you have to install it. How did you install opencv? Do link static or dynamic against opencv?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Can you tell if i can use the shared library as .so file or it is different? I actually need a .so file to create a python object.

Comment: A .so file is a shared library aka shared object

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, giving me an

```
OSError: /lib64/libarmadillo.so.9: undefined symbol: H5Ovisit
```

in python, when calling

```
libCustCv = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./../so/opencv_cust.so')
```

To resolve this, I did the following:

1. In the cpp files, I replaced the general import `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` by the specific ones: `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` and `#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`
2. Instead of giving the bash-output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` as arguments of the compilation command (which gave quite a list), I just used the specific flags:
   `g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include/opencv4 -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -Wall -Wl,-soname,opencv_cust.so -o opencv_cust.so opencv_cust.cpp`